# Why are screen recordings on MacOS unable to be played once copy/pasted to a usb drive?

Tags: image-processing, filesystems

If I take a screen recording in MacOS, (seemingly regardless of file size) and copy/paste it into a usb drive, then try to play the .mov file from the usb (on a Mac)I get the error:

`The document <file_name> couldn't be opened. The file isn't compatible with QuickTime Player.`

Why is this happening and what can be done to avoid in the future? The video file plays fine if attempted from the desktop (where the file originated)

If the screen-shot video is compressed and copied to the usb drive, then attempted to extract, there is a "Extraction failed" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a faulty USB drive.

The only other thing I can think of - and this is a long shot - is that the USB drive is formatted as FAT32, and the video is larger than 4 GB.

Given that both viewing and extracting a compressed file fail, though, it sounds like the bytes being written to the drive aren't coming out the same. Have you tried another USB drive?

Comment: the files that *do* play, are on average 1.5-2.2 gb in size. the files that dont play are larger, yes. but there's also a 3gb file that won't play. also, I reformatted the drive to ExFAT. I haven't tried another drive. its my only one at the moment

Comment: Interesting! FAT16 has a hard 2 GB limit... 2.2 GB is just over 2 GiB, so it could be a filesystem issue (and relevant to units of measurement). I'm assuming you reformatted to ExFAT before these failed tests? If so, I'm out of ideas other than corruption.

Comment: it was a super cheap "2TB" usb stick for around $30. decent chance its crap?

Comment: I've heard there are some sticks on the market (though I've never seen one in person) which are altered so that they report a larger size than they actually are. This may be what you have. Can you point to a product page or some other details about your specific unit? The going rate for a drive of that size is at least double what you paid.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/2TB-256GB-USB-Flash-Drive-Thumb-U-Disk-Memory-Stick-Pen-PC-Laptop-Storage-USA/283587547192@pageci=e280f7fd-e18f-4292-8c03-f66eb40a4a63

Comment: The current price I see at https://www.ebay.com/itm/2TB-256GB-USB-Flash-Drive-Thumb-U-Disk-Memory-Stick-Pen-PC-Laptop-Storage-USA/283587547192 is $11! Definitely a scam. Sorry about that!

Comment: its 22 for the 2tb, but weird that it works with some files but not others. ugh. thanks